# Как добавить тег интернационализации в существующий блок {% %}?

Tags: django, шаблоны

в шаблоне Джанго 1.4 нужно добавить {% trans 'Services' %}
в {% get_contactform 0 'Услуги' %}
get_contactform - это тег плагина

Если пишу так **{% get_contactform 0 trans 'Services' %}**
то плагин не может принять три параметра 0 trans 'Services' вместо двух предусмотренных

Если так **{% get_contactform 0 "trans 'Services'" %**}
то trans не обрабатывается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% trans 'Services' as form_title %}
{% get_contactform 0 form_title %}
```